# WeakReference understanding

Tags: c#, wpf, weak-references

I want to create the dictionary of all the ViewModels.

```
   public static Dictionary<string, WeakReference> vmCollection = new Dictionary<string, WeakReference>();
```

Adding it like this

```
 vmCollection.Add(name, new WeakReference(viewModel));
```

And calling the required method like this..

```
((vmCollection[viewModel].Target) as BaseViewModel).NewMessage(message);
```

Do I need maintain it as a `WeakReference`? What could be the consequences if I don't maintain it as a `WeakReference`.

Comment: don't forget to check if the object is alive before accessing it - IsAlive on the WeakReference

Comment: If you are looking to implement a messaging type solution then have you looked at the EventAggregator in Prism?

Comment: Thanks slugster.I want to implement it on my own to avoid any kind of dependncy...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The only consequence of not using a `WeakReference` is that the reference in your dictionary will prevent the View Model instances from being garbage collected. A `WeakReference` allows garbage collection (assuming there are no other solid references elsewhere).

An item becomes eligible for garbage collection when it has no references to it. `WeakReference` does not create a "countable" reference, thus you can keep a sort-of-reference to it, but still let it be eligible if your `WeakReference` is the only thing left looking at it.

Whether you need it or not really depends on what sort of life-cycle your View Models have. If they need disposing or otherwise "letting go of", then you may need to use `WeakReference` or expose a way to remove the reference from the dictionary instead.

As I mention in the comments. I tend to err away from using `WeakReference` as opposed to handling the life-cycle of the relevant objects explicitly. That said, they are useful when you simply don't have visibility of the life-cycle at the relevant points. I think in your situation, you should have the necessary visibility, as these are all likely in the UI layer, and thus should try to *not* use them.

Here is a resource on the topic:

- [Weak References MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/weak-references)

Guidelines extract from the above MSDN link:

> Use long weak references only when necessary as the state of the
>   object is unpredictable after finalization.
>
> Avoid using weak references to small objects because the pointer
>   itself may be as large or larger.
>
> Avoid using weak references as an automatic solution to memory
>   management problems. Instead, develop an effective caching policy for
>   handling your application's objects.

I believe the last guideline point applies to your situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Adam. will it be any sort of OverHead if on the safer side i use it?

Comment: @RaoBHavik The overhead will be the cost of the `WeakReference` object instance itself, and the need to constantly check if the object that is referenced is still usable (obviously, it could have been collected since you last used it). I would always err away from using them as opposed to handling the life-cycle of objects explicitly, but sometimes you just don't have visibility of the life-cycle so they can prove useful. I think in your case you should have visibility so should likely try to not use them.

Answer (score 0):

I took a slightly different approach.

For this example, I only have a **single instance**, but I'm sure it's fairly easily extendable for multiple instances...

So, on my class I create the following Action (it could be a Func if you need something returned).  For my example, I'm just pushing an Exception around:

```
private  static Action<Exception> StaticAccessorToInstanceMethod { get; set; }
```

And the instance method I want to call is:

```
public void HandleExceptionDetails(Exception e)
{
    // Content of the method on the instance
}
```

I then have this in my constructor:

```
StaticAccessorToInstanceMethod = this.HandleExceptionDetails;
```

And the following in the destructor:

```
StaticAccessorToInstanceMethod = null;
```

(If you're dealing with multiple instances, then the constructor and destructor code would be a bit different).

Then the static method simply calls the instance method:

```
public static void HandleGeneralException(Exception ex)
{    
     StaticAccessorToInstanceMethod(result);
}
```

I've left out defensive logic.